# Java unexpected Stop The Worlds on a KVM

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

Does anybody also expirience the unexpected Stop The Worlds pauses in JVM (Java 7 and 8 Hotspot) running on a KVM? I think, due to the virtualization, other KVMs on the hardware could take processing time from my JVM. Is it possible? Could you solve the problem and how?

My garbage collector graphs look normal. A minor gc happens every 15 minutes, so I think it couldn't be the cause of the often STWs.

Comment: You can get random pauses of around 50 ms in a virtualised operating system, more if the system is busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you run a JVM which does nothing by monitor jitter. e.g. 
[MicroJitterSampler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity/blob/master/affinity/src/test/java/net/openhft/affinity/MicroJitterSampler.java)

This will help baseline the jitter your system is getting.
e.g. on a clean machine you might expect to get

```
2us 78400
3us 122703
4us 345238
6us 216098
8us 78694
10us    3977528
14us    114495
20us    4931
30us    203
40us    35
60us    18
80us    11
100us   9
140us   132
200us   85
300us   473
400us   5
1ms 24
```

This is normalised as to the jitter per hour.

With affinity you can get this much lower.  On a virtualised machine you might expect to see 5 - 50 ms on an otherwise quiet machine.